# Rails caching does not generate static view files in /public

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I'm just trying to get caching to work in my local development environment. I have:

1. `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` in `development.rb`
2. In the view HAML, insert `- cache do`
3. `Application.config.action_controller.page_cache_directory` is at `/public`

When I visit the above page in localhost, it seems that Rails still tries to retrieve everything instead of a single static file. And I don't see the cached file in `/public`.

Can anyone let me know what I'm missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be conflating page caching (where the entire response is saved in public, allowing rails to be bypassed on the next request) with fragment caching, where the controller code still runs, views are still rendered but portions of the view can be cached.

The `cache` helper uses the fragment cache, (exactly where the fragment is saved depends in your configuration but the default is in tmp/cache) so it's normal for nothing to appear in /public

The [rails caching guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) has more details on the differences.